# Problems when uploading cakephp app to hosting

Tags: cakephp, web-hosting

I have a cakephp app, working smoothly on my local server, but when I upload to the hosting it does not work online

I am using wamp server on windows to develop my local app.

How to make it work?

This is the ERROR:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '(' in /home/boga/public_html/system/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php on line 136

I am using cakephp 2.0.5 stable

the link -> www.solucionestelecon.com.ve/proyectos

Comment: The strange thing is that it's happening in one of the core Cake files. Line 136 has the following content: `App::$bootstrapping = true;`. Does your server configuration meet the requirements for running Cake 2.0?

Comment: Which are those requeriments?

Comment: Cake *does* have a manual, you know: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html

Comment: Yes it does, but i can´t edit apache settings, it says something about .htacces but i think that is not the issue here, i do not know why it gives me this specific error when on my localhost works smoothly

Comment: So it meets the requirements? Is anything other than the parse error logged in the Apache logs? You should have access to those, even if you're on shared hosting.

Comment: Still looking for the logs, the hosting uses dpanel

Comment: Ok, changed the php version now it gives me other error, it can´t find the views. Changed the url http://www.solucionestelecon.com.ve/proyectos/

Comment: Have you actually created `login.ctp` in your `Views` directory?

Comment: Yes, i did, it looks to be some issue with htaccess, the error changed from 500 to 400 editing those files

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be a problem with apache remods (htaccess files)

I changed them and gave me error 500 Internal Server Error

Edited again and now gives me error 400 Bad Request